# onCreate and onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle) not called after startActivityForResult

Tags: android, android-intent, oncreate, onactivityresult

I'm trying to load an image from gallery.
This is the `onCreate()` :

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_gallery_picture);

    mThis = this;
    mImageCache = new TakingPictureActivityCacheMngr(this);

    initUi();

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        openGallery();
    }
}
```

Here is the `onSaveInstanceState()`:

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    // save file url in bundle as it will be null on scren orientation
    // changes
    outState.putParcelable("file_uri", mFileUri);
    if (com.isee.spot.toolkit.Config.IS_DEBUG) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Instance was saved.");
    }
}
```

On restore : (never called)

```
@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

    // get the file Uri
    mFileUri = savedInstanceState.getParcelable("file_uri");
}
```

The `onCreate()` is never called after opening the gallery, `onDestroy()` is called right when the gallery is opened and so it the `onSaveInstanceState()`.

Here is the activity declaration in the manifest :

```
<activity
    android:name=".GalleryPictureActivity"
    android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard|keyboardHidden"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
</activity>
```

I overloaded the `onActivityResult()` :

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    // if the result is loading image from gallery
    if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
    ...
```

Comment: this is the onCreate of what - your custom image picking class ? Why dont you just use the ACTION_PICK intent ?

Comment: This is just activity to show the selected image in ImageView.

Comment: Ok... does the code in the answer fire the restore? I'm curious as to why destroy is being called...

Comment: Nope, restore isn't called.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the answer,
The activity itself was correct.
The problem is with the activity which start it, I used : `galleryPic.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);`
Apparently this cause the `onActivityResult(int, int, Intent)` not be called.
Leaving this just for the chance of someone getting same behavior.
Thank you for trying to help, I guess you had no chance.

Answer (score 0):

I may not be understanding the context of this code properly, but it looks like this is a custom image picking class ? You may be aware - but perhaps not - that there are built in SDK methods for this... see below:

```
private void pickImage() {
    Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
    photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
    startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, REQUEST_PICK_IMAGE);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(final int requestCode, final int resultCode, final Intent data) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case REQUEST_PICK_IMAGE:
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                Log.v(TAG, "User Picked An Image");
                handleImage(data.getData());
            } 
            else if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) { 
               Log.v(TAG, "User Cancelled Pick Image");
            }
            break;

        default:
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            break;
    }
}

private void handleImage(final Uri selectedImage) {
    String filePath = selectedImage.getEncodedPath();
    Log.v(TAG, " -- picked image is " + filePath);
    MyImageView.setImage(selectedImage);
}
```